# Match an array with an object property

Tags: javascript, object, find, higher-order-functions

I've got an object with properties which look like this:

```js
{
  maj6: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7, 9 ] },
  min6: { chromatic: [ 0, 3, 7, 9 ] },
  maj7: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7, 11 ] },
  min7: { chromatic: [ 0, 3, 7, 10 ] },
  minmaj7: { chromatic: [ 0, 3, 7, 11 ] },
  dom7: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7, 10 ] },
  maj9: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7, 11, 14 ] },
  dom9: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7, 10, 14 ] },
  maj: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7 ] },
  min: { chromatic: [ 0, 3, 7 ] },
  aug: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 8 ] },
  dim: { chromatic: [ 0, 3, 6 ] }
}
```

I'm computing an array, such as [0,4,7] that I am trying to match to one of these aforementioned object properties. I am trying to use the find function in order to achieve this, as seen in the following code snippet:

```
  matchParsedToChord() {
    const result = this.blocks //returns larger payload
    .map(block => block.chromatic) // returns array [0,4,7,4,7,7,7,4]
    .filter((v,i,arr) => arr.indexOf(v) === i) //removes redundancies  [0,4,7]
    .find(v => { //attempts to 
      v === Object.keys(chordDefinitions).map(key => chordDefinitions[key].chromatic)
    })
    console.log(result)
  }
```

My problem is that the Object.keys logic returns an entire array, whereas I'd like to do an element-by-element comparison.

I would like to return the object property associated with the array, for example:

`maj: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7 ] }`

Many thanks

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: Have you looked into [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#findKey)? The `_.findKey` function might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @Nakul - did any of these solutions take care of your question? If so, please accept an answer. If not, please reply why not so we can help. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This will return all chords that have pattern you're looking for. It simply flattens the arrays and looks for indexOf to assemble all matches. Can run it as strict (exact match) or contains (all partial matches)

```js
const a = {
  maj6: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7, 9 ] },
  min6: { chromatic: [ 0, 3, 7, 9 ] },
  maj7: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7, 11 ] },
  min7: { chromatic: [ 0, 3, 7, 10 ] },
  minmaj7: { chromatic: [ 0, 3, 7, 11 ] },
  dom7: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7, 10 ] },
  maj9: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7, 11, 14 ] },
  dom9: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7, 10, 14 ] },
  maj: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7 ] },
  min: { chromatic: [ 0, 3, 7 ] },
  aug: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 8 ] },
  dim: { chromatic: [ 0, 3, 6 ] }
}

function getPattern(pattern, strict) {
  let b = []
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(a)) {
   let set = Object.values(value).flat().join(",") ;
    if ((!strict && set.indexOf(pattern) !== -1) || (strict && set == pattern)) b.push({
      [key]: value
    })
  }
  if (strict && b.length>0) b = b[0];
  return b;
}

// Contains (partial matches)
let matches = getPattern("0,4,7", false);
console.log('Contains', matches);

// strict
matches = getPattern("0,4,7", true);
console.log('Strict', matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?
Edited to use reduce to get desired return

```js
const a = {
  maj6: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7, 9 ] },
  min6: { chromatic: [ 0, 3, 7, 9 ] },
  maj7: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7, 11 ] },
  min7: { chromatic: [ 0, 3, 7, 10 ] },
  minmaj7: { chromatic: [ 0, 3, 7, 11 ] },
  dom7: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7, 10 ] },
  maj9: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7, 11, 14 ] },
  dom9: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7, 10, 14 ] },
  maj: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7 ] },
  min: { chromatic: [ 0, 3, 7 ] },
  aug: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 8 ] },
  dim: { chromatic: [ 0, 3, 6 ] }
}

const find = (obj, match = [0,4,7]) => {
  return Object.keys(a)
  .reduce((acc, k) => {
    // If you want more loose match, just switch search direction
    // like: match.every(m => obj[k].chromatic.includes(m)
    if(obj[k].chromatic.every(m =>  match.includes(m))) {
      acc[k] = obj[k];
    }
    return acc;
  },
  {})
}
console.log(find(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Array#every() and match the lengths as well. It's not really clear what the results are you are looking for though so this likely needs modifying depending on your expectations

```js
const data ={
  maj6: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7, 9 ] },
  min6: { chromatic: [ 0, 3, 7, 9 ] },
  maj7: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7, 11 ] },
  min7: { chromatic: [ 0, 3, 7, 10 ] },
  minmaj7: { chromatic: [ 0, 3, 7, 11 ] },
  dom7: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7, 10 ] },
  maj9: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7, 11, 14 ] },
  dom9: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7, 10, 14 ] },
  maj: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 7 ] },
  min: { chromatic: [ 0, 3, 7 ] },
  aug: { chromatic: [ 0, 4, 8 ] },
  dim: { chromatic: [ 0, 3, 6 ] }
}

const arr =  [0,4,7];

const entries = Object.entries(data).map(([k,v])=> [k, [...new Set(v.chromatic)]]);

const match = entries.find(([k,v])=> v.length === arr.length && arr.every(n => v.includes(n)))

console.log(match)
```

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't be using `find()` on they array you got from `this.blocks`. That will just return a single number like `3`.

I assume you want to return the entry in `chordDefinitions` that matches that whole array. So you should put that array into a variable, then search `chordDefinitions` for an equal `chromatic` property.

I've converted it to a `Set` to remove duplicates and also make searching more efficient.

```js
function matchParsedToChord() {
  const chord = new Set(
    this.blocks //returns larger payload
    .map(block => block.chromatic) // returns array [0,4,7,4,7,7,7,4]
  ); // Converting to Set removes duplicates
  const chordSize = thisChord.size;
  const result = Object.entries(chordDefinitions)
    .find(([name, val]) => val.chromatic.length == chordSize && val.chromatic.every(v => chord.has(v)));
  console.log(result)
}
```